# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Home'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have just began learning React, and have stumbled upon this error while trying to build using webpack.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Home' in 'D:\wamp64\www\Wallet\src\components'
resolve 'Home' in 'D:\wamp64\www\Wallet\src\components'
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: '.src/index.js',
    js: './src/js/index2.js',
    react: './src/components/App.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['env', 'stage-0', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  return <h1>Home</h1>
}

export default Home
```

This is how I've imported Home in App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch , Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from 'Home';
import About from 'About';
```

I came across few questions on here, which suggested adding an empty index.js in src folder, but that too didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `import Home from './Home';`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava seems like I was passing a the wrong path all this while. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your import is not correct

```
import Home from 'Home';
import About from 'About';
```

you need to specify the path and of the file, for example:

```
import Home from './src/components/Home.js';
```

home.js is the file where you exported your component